# Design of mapping table and query

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a mapping table which we join with main table to derive necessary values. In mapping table if a particular column's set of values matches then derive respective values, if any other value derive other set of  value.
Ex :
In below map_tbl if main table FIELD3 falls into (02,08,09,11) then derive TCODE and RCODE if FIELD3 falls into any other value then derive one against field3 with value "OTHER"

Create Script for mapping table

```
CREATE TABLE "MAP_TBL" ("DB_KEY" VARCHAR2(200) , "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(200),"FIELD3" VARCHAR2(200) , "ICODE" VARCHAR2(200) , "TCODE" VARCHAR2(200) , "RCODE" VARCHAR2(200) );
```

```
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','02','1','BD','AT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','08','1','BD','AT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','09','1','BD','AT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','11','1','BD','AT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','OTHER','1','LD','AT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','02','3','AD','VT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','08','3','AD','VT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','09','3','AD','VT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','11','3','AD','VT');
Insert into MAP_TBL (DB_KEY,COUNTRY,FIELD3,ICODE,TCODE,RCODE) values ('ABE','BE','OTHER','3','FD','FT');
COMMIT;
```

Main table create script

```
create TABLE "STD_TBL" ("DB_KEY" VARCHAR2(200),"SNO" VARCHAR2(200), "FIELD3" VARCHAR2(200),"COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(200),"ICODE" VARCHAR2(200));
```

Insert script for main table

```
Insert into STD_TBL (DB_KEY,SNO,FIELD3,COUNTRY,ICODE) values ('ABE','123','02','BE','1');
Insert into STD_TBL (DB_KEY,SNO,FIELD3,COUNTRY,ICODE) values ('ABE','124','01','BE','1');
Insert into STD_TBL (DB_KEY,SNO,FIELD3,COUNTRY,ICODE) values ('ABE','125','02','BE','3');
Insert into STD_TBL (DB_KEY,SNO,FIELD3,COUNTRY,ICODE) values ('ABE','126','03','BE','3');
COMMIT;
```

I tried using case when statement in where clause

```
(case when lpad(STD_TBL.field3,2,0) not in ('02','08','11','09') then 'OTHER' else lpad(taxtbl.field3,2,0) end) = MAP_TBL.field3 (+)
```

Comment: Use `CASE` logic as you've started to do, but in the `SELECT` clause, not in the `JOIN` or `WHERE` clauses. For your join, simply outer join `map_tbl.field3` to `std_tbl.field3`. No conditional logic (or `lpad`/`substr` work) needed in the join itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that we do outer join and add case when statement in the select if customfield3 is "OTHER"  fill other field values?

Comment: You can present anything you want as the column value in your `select` clause. Write a `case` statement to emit OTHER in one situation, some column value in other. Just don't put that logic in the join.

Answer (score 0):

You only have two tables `STD_TBL` and `MAP_TBL` so trying to use an table name/alias of `TAXTBL` is invalid as there is not third table.

Your `FIELD3` values are all at least 2 characters long so `LPAD` appears to be redundant (and may erroneously truncate longer values).

Just join the two tables and use a `CASE` expression (or `DECODE`) in the `ON` condition of the `JOIN` and then `SELECT` the `tcode` and `rcode` columns from the mapping table:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       m.tcode,
       m.rcode
FROM   std_tbl s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN map_tbl m
       ON (   s.db_key = m.db_key
          AND s.country = m.country
          AND s.icode = m.icode
          AND CASE
              WHEN s.field3 NOT IN ('02', '08', '11', '09')
              THEN 'OTHER'
              ELSE s.field3
              END = m.field3
          )
```

or:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       m.tcode,
       m.rcode
FROM   std_tbl s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN map_tbl m
       ON (   s.db_key = m.db_key
          AND s.country = m.country
          AND s.icode = m.icode
          AND DECODE(s.field3, '02', '02',
                               '08', '08',
                               '11', '11',
                               '09', '09',
                               'OTHER') = m.field3
          )
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| DB_KEY | SNO | FIELD3 | COUNTRY | ICODE | TCODE | RCODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABE | 123 | 02 | BE | 1 | BD | AT |
| ABE | 124 | 01 | BE | 1 | LD | AT |
| ABE | 125 | 02 | BE | 3 | AD | VT |
| ABE | 126 | 03 | BE | 3 | FD | FT |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FsUJgzVW)

Comment: Thanks for details. Will there be any performance impact if we do case when statement during join condition

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you realy want to get as a result from this query.
Here is how I understood your desscriptive question - join two tables to get std_tbl data along with matching map_tbl data from columns TCODE and RCODE dpending on FIELD3 values.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    map_tbl (DB_KEY, COUNTRY, FIELD3, ICODE, TCODE, RCODE) AS
        ( Select 'ABE','BE','02','1','BD','AT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','08','1','BD','AT' From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABE','BE','09','1','BD','AT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','11','1','BD','AT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','OTHER','1','LD','AT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','02','3','AD','VT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','08','3','AD','VT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','09','3','AD','VT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','11','3','AD','VT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABE','BE','OTHER','3','FD','FT' From Dual 
        ),
    std_tbl (DB_KEY, SNO, FIELD3, COUNTRY, ICODE) AS 
        ( Select 'ABE','123','02','BE','1' From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABE','124','01','BE','1' From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABE','125','02','BE','3' From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABE','126','03','BE','3' From Dual
        )
```

...

```sql
--    S Q L :
SELECT    s.DB_KEY, s.COUNTRY, s.ICODE, s.SNO, 
          Case When s.FIELD3 Not In('02', '08', '11', '09') Then 'OTHER' Else s.FIELD3 End "FIELD3",
          Case When s.FIELD3 Not In('02', '08', '11', '09') Then Null Else m.TCODE End "TCODE", 
          Case When s.FIELD3 Not In('02', '08', '11', '09') Then Null Else m.RCODE End "RCODE" 
FROM      std_tbl s
LEFT JOIN map_tbl m ON ( s.DB_KEY = m.DB_KEY And 
                         s.COUNTRY = m.COUNTRY And 
                         s.ICODE = m.ICODE And 
                         s.FIELD3 = m.FIELD3
                       )
ORDER BY s.SNO
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
DB_KEY COUNTRY ICODE SNO FIELD3 TCODE RCODE
------ ------- ----- --- ------ ----- -----
ABE    BE      1     123 02     BD    AT
ABE    BE      1     124 OTHER      
ABE    BE      3     125 02     AD    VT
ABE    BE      3     126 OTHER             */
```